# Swift - freezing when UITextField is IBDesignable with UIColor.init AND isSecureText

Tags: swift, uitextfield, uicolor, ibdesignable

I have a `UITextField` whose class is `myCustomTextField`.  When myCustomTextField sets the `textColor` of the text field with `UIColor.init` **and** sets `isSecureText` to `true`, the app freezes after I type some text in the UITextField and then click off of the textfield.

The app does not crash and there is no error – the app just freezes and the only way to exit is to kill the app.

If I only set the `textColor` or only set `isSecureText` to `true`, the app does not freeze.

**myCustomTextField:**

```
@IBDesignable class myCustomTextField: UITextField {

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        updateSomeStuff()
    }

    @IBInspectable var Style : Int = 0 {
        didSet {
            updateSomeStuff()
        }
    }

    // set textColor and isSecureTextEntry
    func updateSomeStuff() {
        if Style == 0 {
            textColor = UIColor.init(red: 122/255, green: 53/255, blue: 74/255, alpha: 1)
            //  self.textColor = UIColor.init(red: 122/255, green: 53/255, blue: 74/255, alpha: 1) // alternative attempt
            isSecureTextEntry = true
            //  self.isSecureTextEntry = true  // alternative attempt
        }
    }
}
```

The app does not freeze when I set the text color without calling `init`, but I am not sure how to resolve the issue since I need to set a specific text color.

Changed:

```
textColor = UIColor.init(red: 122/255, green: 53/255, blue: 74/255, alpha: 1)
```

To:

```
textColor = UIColor.red
```

**Does anyone have ideas as to why setting the `textColor` with `UIColor.init` and setting `isSecureText` to `true` causes the app to freeze after typing and then clicking outside of the UITextField?**

Comment: It is Swift naming convention to name all your classes starting with an UppercaseLetter and all your instance variables with a lowercase letter.

Comment: @LeoDabus does this relate to the problem or solution?

Comment: IMO  your issue it is not related to setting the secure property and or omitting or not the init but I am not saying that fixing the naming will solve your issue but it is a good start

Comment: This doesn't seem to relate to any of the conditions that you have mentioned. Can you please show some error logs, or tell more about how you are implementing this?

Comment: I have tried your custom class and didnt notice any freeze. My only advice is to move your `updateSomeStuff()` function to an override `init()` / `awakeFromNib()` because you dont need to set `isSecureTextEntry` to true each time `layoutSubviews()`, is called.